# Foreach loop can cause thread concurrency?

Tags: java, concurrency, foreach

I've heard that you shouldn't use foreach loop where you can avoid it because it can cause thread concurrency, what does it mean thread concurrency, and is it true ?

Comment: Well for starters you should google "concurrency"

Comment: I think you should go back to wherever you heard that and ask for more details. An enhanced for loop doesn't *cause* concurrency... it can have issues when you're modifying a collection while iterating over it, but that's an inherent problem.

Comment: ajb, is that a joke? haha, because i actually giggled when i read that. I'd say "can" is a bit of an understatement

Answer (score 1):

> ## [So when should you use the for-each loop?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
>
> **Any time you can**. It really beautifies your code. Unfortunately, you cannot use it everywhere. Consider, for example, [the expurgate method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html#expurgate). The program needs access to the iterator in order to remove the current element. **The for-each loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove**. Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly **it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it**. Finally, **it is not usable for loops that must iterate over multiple collections in parallel**.
>
> These shortcomings were known by the designers, who made a conscious decision to go with a clean, simple construct that would cover the great majority of cases.

Emphasis mine.

Unless you clear up what you mean with exactly, this would indicate that you're wrong.

Comment: does java have a .ToList() function on collections? if it does, would it work like c#'s .ToList(), where you can modify the original collection while in a foreach loop?

Comment: `.ToList()` in C# simply creates a new list to iterate over, you don't remove and iterate over the same list.

Comment: I know, i mean you can call remove on the original list with the current item in the foreach loop

Comment: So like foreach(var item in collectionObj.ToList()){collectionObj.remove(item);}

Answer (score 0):

Using a for each loop when altering a collection can trigger it to incorrectly detect a concurrent modification which looks like it has been modified by another thread when in fact it has been modified by the same thread.

"for each" doesn't have anything to do with concurrency.  You can find the ConcurrentModicationException a number of way, one is to use Iterator.remove().

Comment: I'd say that is in fact the correct behavior.  A foreach loop creates an iterator on the collection, and any "structural modification" (particularly adding or removing an element), regardless of which thread caused it, can cause the collection to reorganize itself, which would invalidate the iterator.  Requiring that an iterator still be valid after such an operation imposes all kinds of limitations on how the iterator can work, and all but requires that the collection expose some implementation details so the iterator can re-sync itself.

Comment: @cHao I agree it is correct behaviour.  What is not clear to many developers is that; this has nothing to do with multiple threads running or one thread modifying a collection while another is reading it.

Comment: It does seem a bit non-obvious at first.  The issue seems to be the use of the word "concurrent" to refer to both cross-thread interactions in general, and same-thread interactions with a collection currently being iterated over.  I wish there were a better word for one or the other.